# Deploying Confluence to OpenShift?

Tags: spring, tomcat6, confluence, openshift, chown

I deployed Confluence 5.1 as a WAR to an OpenShift Tomcat 6 Cartridge.

Visiting the instance with my web-browser I get:

> Error occurred during template rendering: Velocimacro : Error using VM library : template/includes/macros-deprecated.vm. Contact your administrator for assistance.

With the relevant portion of the server logs saying:

```
2013-04-14 05:32:03,322 FATAL [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] [atlassian.spring.container.SpringContainerContext] getComponent Spring Application  context has not been set
2013-04-14 05:32:03,323 ERROR [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] [confluence.user.listeners.UserSessionExpiryListener] sessionDestroyed Application server does not give us access to expired sessions. Listeners that depend on receiving LogoutEvent will not be reliable.  This web server is probably unsupported.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spring Application context has not been set
```

Atlassian support tells me to chown the Tomcat directories; but OpenShift doesn't seem to allow this.

How can I successfully install Confluence 5.1 on OpenShift?

Comment: This may be more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Well it seemed similar to the question of a similar name; posted in January: here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DIY cartridge and deploy tomcat yourself. Using an action hook (for example the *deploy* hook) you could also adjust permissions if this is still required.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having a little trouble getting a Tomcat server running on DIY cartridge. Followed this guide: http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2241, except used Tomcat 6 and instead of 127.3.45.2 I used the IP address from OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP). I am getting 503 errors.

Comment: Try the git QuickStart https://github.com/openshift/openshift-tomcat-quickstart. Also make sure to check the log files.